# Dealing with multiple checkbox in a form with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes representing the cost; the value of those comes from the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="12.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="40.00" />
```

On submitting the form, I use javascript to add the checked values together and post that new value in a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="total_cost" value="" />
```

I need to pass the row id from the database with the cost value for each checkbox. that way, when I check one or more checkboxes and submit the payment I need to change the status to PAID from NOT PAID.

Note: It is not possible for me to change the status while checking  the checkbox. I can only change the status only after all the the transaction is completed.

[image]

Comment: You say that you use JS. Put on each row (tr as example) an attr with the id, then read it before submitting the data and aggregate them with Js.

Comment: Why calculate the total cost in js unless you use it for display? You are just going to have to recalculate on the server side anyway to validate that the sum of items is correct. You should never trust client side input.

Comment: Don't do this in client-side code. What's to stop someone from fiddling with the form values and changing their invoice totals to $0, or even "$-500" and giving themselves a nice "refund"?

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['var'])){ $status = "PAID"; }else{ $status = "NOT PAID"; }`

Comment: Thankyou @MikeBrant and MarcB, I didn't expect that sort of loophole.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually I can only change the status after getting a positive response from the payment gateway.

Comment: That's the logic behind it. A method I use myself. If something is checked, value equals something. Else, it equals something else. UPDATE table accordingly.

Comment: @MikeBrant if i am doing the sum of cost in the server-side, how can i get the an extra attribute value of that particular row when it was checked. Let say the row id of that particular cost's from the Database

Answer (score 3):

First of all naming your multiple form's element in this way will not send multiple data. You have to name your elements like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="12.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="40.00" />
```

Note the square brackets `[]` in the name attribute of the element.

Comment: I don't know why another person deleted their answer, it was the same thing as this.

Comment: @sємsєм that I have made. So now can you please suggest to send the row id of that checked amount to the server. By row Id meant the id in the database for the respective costs. Thank you

Comment: @AbuIsaac Change the monetary values to the ID's you need and check will be an array with all ID's that are checked by the user.

Comment: @René thankyou very much. That is how I wanted. Thanks again. I am not sure whether you have suggested in this way. Anyway I am going to do this as follows: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="{row id from db}">$12.00</input>

Comment: You have two options: Using javascript or jquery make all fields under the parent element with unchecked checkbox disabled so there values will not send to the server and only those checked are send. OR make the value of check box composite value i.e 12.00-xx where xx is the database id then explode it on the server side to get its id and amount. @AbuIsaac

Comment: Checkboxes cannot contain text nodes. You could write `<label><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='{the_id}' /> $12.00</label>`. But in your case you don't need the label and textnode because the monetary value is elsewhere in the row as well.

Comment: @René Do you mean that I could not make checkbox like that `<input type="checkbox" value="YES" />` ?

Comment: @sємsєм That's not what I meant with not being able to hold a textnode. That's just a string value. What's not possible is `<input>TEXTNODE</input>`. That's more limited to `<textarea>` and a whole lot of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

The issue i faced here is to get the row id from the db for respective Cost in the server side. Finally I got a solution from @rene by setting the input value as the ID of the row from the database. Hope it works.

Solution I got: `<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="{row id from the database}" />`

So I will get the Cost for each checked row at the server side by using the ID (value of input). Also I can update the status of each COST by having the respective row IDs after getting the positive response from the payment gateway and not if the response is negative.

Thank you all for the suggestions.